# Get a Flask script on the backend to communicate with the user's local database: possible?

Tags: database, reactjs, flask, directory, element

I have a Flask server and a React front. The main "actors" in the setup are (1) an excel sheet containing on the order 500 patient IDs, other biomarkers and 
(2) ***a local(for each user)*** folder/"database" with 500 xml files containing those patients' complete ECG recordings.

Previously this application worked by letting the user upload a *single* .xml file to flask, where my scripts parsed it and returned a scalar. 
So, upload a patient file -> get a patient "score" at the front.

At this point, my **Flask needs to accept an excel sheet** with multiple patient IDs, **pull the corresponding xml files from the folder (on the user's system)**, **run the scripts on each**, and write the scalar result to the excel file, **return an excel** updated with scores.

---

*My question is how to establish communication between the back-end flask script and a folder which is contained on the user computer?*

---

The idea of the application is that the doctor uploads an excel with ids, specifies the directory containing the xml recordings corresponding to these ids and gets a result of a calculation added to their html based on these recordings and it seems unrealistic to send the whole database over an http request.

I've read some people saying that the input-file tag is the best that you can do for security reasons, but this doesn't seem right. It seems like a regular issue and i wonder what's the industry's solution to it.

I'm not hellbent on this particular architecture either so long as the idea functions.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: For many security reasons web servers can't have access to client filesystem.

Comment: Store your xml files in real database.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa, i would love to make use of a static database, but unfortunately it's not "mine" in a sense that the user/the doctor who has done the ECGs and has the recording files generated by the machine is supposed to provide them.

Comment: you may have to think about writing a standalone app / script, that will reside and run in the local computer itself.